# Regex Issue Replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to use Regex to remove the `( )` and anything in the `( )`.

For example, string: `3 Series  (11,879)`

To be replaced to: `3 Series`

What I have tried:

```
preg_replace("/(\w+)/","","3 Series  (11,879)");
```

The output is just: `(,)`

Comment: w is for word so it doesn't match punctuation and you have to escape hte parenthesis since they are used for composing the regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo preg_replace('/\h*\([^)]*\)/', "", "3 Series  (11,879)");
//=> 3 Series
```

i.e.escape the `(` and `)` and match everything between them using `[^)]*`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the parenthesis.  Here I use a non greedy match to find stuff in parenthesis [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sM3uO2/1):

```
\(.*?\)
```